# how to decide which channel to invoke first?

Tags: spring-integration

i have a code

```html
<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter channel="transactionChannel" 
entity-manager="entityManager" 
jpa-query="select t from Transaction t ,QueueConfiguration q where    t.transactionStatus='RDY2BATCH' and t.partner.partnerId=q.partnerId" 
expect-single-result="false">
<int:poller default="true" fixed-delay="150000" />
</int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter id="configurationReader"
  channel="configurationChannel" entity-manager="entityManager"
  jpa-query="select s from Setting s where s.SettingsCategory.categoryId='1'"
  expect-single-result="false">
</int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

from here my project is start , here i have 2 channels the i want configurationReader to be execute only once when project start as it has static values which i need to read from DB and i will use it in my project . how can i invoke very first time when project start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose we suggest to use `Only Once Trigger` solution:

```
public class OnlyOnceTrigger implements Trigger {

    private final AtomicBoolean done = new AtomicBoolean();

    @Override
    public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
        return !done.getAndSet(true) ? new Date() : null;
    }

}
```

Also you can consider to react to the `ContextRefreshedEvent` and performs the same JPAQL using `<int-jpa:retrieving-outbound-gateway>`.

Comment: can you please give me some link for more info on onlyOnceTrigger and how can i use it in <int-jpa:retrieving-outbound-gateway>

Comment: and how can i use those values through out the application ?

Comment: `<int-jpa:retrieving-outbound-gateway>`? That is fully different story. Here you ask about `<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>`. Another component, another behavior  - a new SO question. Not sure about `values` question. Make it more cleaner or start a new SO question as well.

Comment: ok , please give me more details  how how can i use <int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter> to implement Only once Trigger solution ?

Comment: That component has `<polled>`. That is the place where you can inject onlyOnce to the `trigger` attribute.

Comment: and how to decide which channel will first ? or how to assign order as i have 2 inbound-channel-adapter?

Comment: Why do you need order for them? Any inbound consumers are independent. You have to describer your task properly. Although that really looks like a new question. We have talked here about an `only once`.